# ArcGIS Export Map Operation is returning imageData string, not the expected png Url

Tags: arcgis-10.2, arcgis-server

I am executing an ArcGIS server [Export Map](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcgis-rest-api/index.html#//02r3000000v7000000) operation /service. The JSON response returns a property called `imageData`, and not the expected `href` property containing the Url to the generated png file. I tried a different ArcServer with the exact request and get back the expected result. The MapServer endpoint lists the following Supported Image Format Types: PNG32,PNG24,PNG.

**What needs to be done to the ArcServer to return the expected PNG Url?**

Current Response:

```
{
"imageData": "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAABRQA...
"contentType": "image/png",
"width": 1300,
"height": 385,
```

Expected Response:

```
{
"href": "http://myserver/arcgis/rest/directories/arcgisoutput/Dir/MyMapServer/abcd.png",
"width": 1300,
"height": 385,
....
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll describe what worked for me in such situation. Firstly I saved the map the map service is based on(say, map1.mxd)  with other name (say, map2.mxd). By the way its size decreased twice. Then I created a new map service based on map2. It worked fine: I got href in Export operation.  Then I deleted the old service and map1.mxd , renamed map2 to map1 and recreated the old map service. The problem was fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I have also experienced the same issue with 10.6 services that answer  instead of ,
but my problem happens randomly, I think.
I also noticed that in case of publishing directly from ArcMap 10.6 I have this problem (imageData response);

instead if I create a .sd file and publish it from the web manager then the service returns correctly the href.

Did you find out something about this behaviour?